# Double function name in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Here is the code sample I have a question about:

```
var javascriptObject = {
   functionName1: function functionName2() {

   }
}
```

I understand the concept of an object in the javascript. I understand everything in the code sample except the `functionName2` what is its purpose?

And I saw the code in the real life projects:

```
init: function init() {
        init._base.call(this);
}
```

The code above does not work if I get rid from the second `init`. What does that second function name mean in javascript?

Comment: It helps when it comes to debugging, as it will leave a more descritive stacktrace in the console

Comment: @SterlingArcher, no, it is definitely not just about debugging. The program would not work at all if I would have got rid from the second `init`.

Comment: @scraaappy, and what does `_base` mean here?

Comment: @askerKonanDoylDimas I didn't say it was the only reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object in JS are just name value pairs nothing more

```
var javascriptObject = {
   functionName1: function functionName2() {

   }
}
```

So what your doing is having a object which has a **name** of functionName1 which has the **value** of

```
function functionName2() {}
```

The name of the function stored in this value is functionName2 but this also could be omitted since it is not necessary to invoke the function.

For example you could run the function without the functionName2

```js
var javascriptObject = {
   functionName1: function () {
      return 5;
   }
};


var bar = javascriptObject.functionName1();
console.log(bar);
```